# child ui-view in parent ui-view works wierd angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a probem and as I can not find the solution since 2 days I come back to you, my worries is when I display my view secondaly in my modal, my view Principal disappears, I do not understand why,

this is my ui-route

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    
      $stateProvider
          .state("foo", {
              url: "/foo",
              views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Second': {

                   abstract :true,
                   template: '<h1>foo</h1><a ui-sref="menu">back menu</a>'

                }
               }
          })
          .state("menu", {
              url: "/menu",
              views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Second': {

                   abstract :true,
                   templateUrl: 'menu.html'

                }
               }
          })
          .state("bar", {
              url: "/bar",
              views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Second': {

                   abstract :true,
                   template: '<h1>bar</h1><a ui-sref="menu">back menu</a>'

                }
               }
          })

          .state("connexion", {
              url: "/",
               views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   templateUrl: 'connexion.html'

                }
               }

          })

          .state('agenda', {

            url: "/agenda",
            views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                    templateUrl: 'agenda.html'

                }
            }


        })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    })
```

Can you help me please

Here is a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/l0lHLurCYT4aSHXyMQrI?p=preview

**edit**

my modal bouton is in my view principal but when i open my modal my secondely view is outside of  pricipal view , I do not know how to do the routing

[image: ui-view]

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/21hHYdFsoH4JmCHRcAWo?p=preview).I added a little code to show Home  view like below

```
<button ui-sref="connexion" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <button ui-sref="connexion" class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

in model close

Comment: thanks sir for this But this is not a good solution because when I press the ok or cancel button, it reloads the connection page, in my real programs i have a table with 2000 result, performance point of view is not ideal and Secondly if I press outside the modal it closes and I have nothing more :( but thank you even for your attention

Comment: Sorry I forgot the courtesy i re edit /* Edit **/ i can t put hello guys now sorry

Answer (score 0):

The application behavior is quite weird. In your $ctrl.open method your changing the state by using $state.go. It should only open modal. If you want to redirect somewhere, put this action when modal will be resolved or close modal in ng-click.

```
<li><a ui-sref="foo" ng-click="$ctrl.$uibModalInstance.close()">Route 1</a></li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ir3odoQjPPgSRwbEqrcJ?p=preview

In my plunker I removed the state.go("menu") and I removed whole state menu, because you don't need separate state for modal content. It's bad practice in my opinion. You can put modal content directly into myModalContent.html I did that in my plunker. 
Hope my plunker will be useful. I didn't find place where the Second view is defined so I modified routing to use 'Principal' view.

Comment: thanks guys for your help , but effectively the result is in the first view , but i realy need the menu.html with foo and bar to be inside the second view, my second view is in myModalContent.html in my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/21hHYdFsoH4JmCHRcAWo?p=preview

Comment: It's been 3 days that I'm stuck on it, I'm just wondering if it's actually possible to make a view in a modal

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you want to implement. Usually the modal is appended to body and it covers whole page. That's why the modal is out of the Principal ui-view in DOM tree. You are redirecting to another state and running modal at the same time. In my opinion that why it's hard to reason about the application state.

Answer (score 0):

here is a plunker with the route in page and in modal windows together

ui-route

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$qProvider){    
      $stateProvider

          .state("connexion", {
              url: "/",
               views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   templateUrl: 'connexion.html'

                }
               }

          })

          .state('agenda', {

            url: "/agenda",
            views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   // templateUrl: 'agenda.html'
                    template:'<a ui-sref="view">Open me!</a>'


                }
            }


        })
        .state('modal', {
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'agenda',
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', function($uibModal, $state) {
            $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {

            }
          })
        }]
      })
      .state('view', {
        url: ':id1',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<div class="navbar">'+
                          '<div class="navbar-inner">'+
                          '<h4 class="brand">Quick Start</h4>'+
                          '<ul class="nav">'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="foo">Route 1</a></li>'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="bar">Route 2</a></li>'+
                          '</ul>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '</div>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('foo', {
        url: ':id2',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>foo</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('bar', {
        url: ':id3',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>bar</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

    })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P3RwR9wTAGUKGPFG4fRp?p=preview

ps: just 2 bug ,

1 cant close the modal via button (ok or close)

and 2

error : Possibly unhandled rejection: backdrop click

thanks for your help and for this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/hw9x7B?p=preview